# How to get list of all directories and sub-directories within a directory using PHP

Tags: php

I want to get list of all directory  and sub-directory if parent directory is provided. i am using Apache web server and php as scripting language.

Comment: as @Andrew mentions, we need to see what you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I can recommend to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the documentation from php.net you should try ;)

```
<?php
      $dir    = "/home/user1/";
      $files1 = scandir($dir);

      print_r($files1); 
?>
```

Give me news. Whereas, after, try to said us what you tried ;)

To test if the file is a dir for example: cf: [is_dir documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-dir.php)

```
<?php
var_dump(is_dir('a_file.txt')); // false 
var_dump(is_dir('bogus_dir/abc')); //false

var_dump(is_dir('..')); //true
?>
```

Comment: but that lists all files, not only directories..

Comment: Hi, You have to use is_dir, i think the autor may have found that ^^ i just update the answer